# Debugging Bluetooth 'Driver Error' on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've built a Bluetooth LE HID device which connects to all OS's fine...except Windows 8.1. It connects, but then displays 'Driver Error' and disconnects. How do I begin to debug this problem? Googling around, information is not forthcoming...

Comment: **What does this question have to do with programming?** Right click `Start Button - Device Manager - Right Click root - Scan for Devices` find the faulted one and `Right Click - Properties` and start reading. Also try to find a driver on the manufacturer website *(that's where you need to ask for help)*.

Comment: I think it is likely to be a problem with the HID descriptor, which is programming. But I wasn't sure if it should go here or....superuser? Anyway, yes I've done that, it simply says there is a PnP error. This isn't specific to one driver, it happens on all Windows 8.1 installations. I believe 'Driver Error' is misleading

Comment: Superuser definitely.